# How to improve performance of RestTemplate

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I am writing a Spring Boot application and using RestTemplate to send out a request.

Here is my method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public static JsonNode getResponse(URI uri)
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException, URISyntaxException {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    return restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, JsonNode.class).getBody();

}
```

When I run the above method, it is taking roughly 3 seconds.  When I run the same method in Postman, it is taking roughly 1 second.

What would account for this difference.  Are there opportunities to improve the performance of RestTemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, declare restTemplate as a bean, instead of creating a new one every time.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

**Second**, try getting `Object.class` instead of `JsonNode.class`.

**Third**, try `getForObject()` if you don't need entity but the object itself.

**Forth**, give [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation:-Jackson-Performance) a read. This is the library that spring uses behind the scenes for JSON serialization/deserialization.

Comment: None of these should have any noticeable performance impact (and it's better to use a real POJO or, worst case, a `Map` instead of `JsonNode`).

Comment: Thanks, @chrylis. It's good to know. I absolutely agree with you that this won't bring a significant performance impact. At the end of the day, we have to wait for the request to execute at the other side of the network. However, when you get `Object.class` I think it automatically converts it into the map. I am not sure about this, but do you think this will significantly improve the performance?

Comment: @AlanSereb It will _not_ improve the performance, but it will make the code clearer than returning `Object`.

Comment: For me, using webclient instead of restTemplate worked as object mapping is done parallely with fetching. For my case, I was reading ~10^5 size array from an API, deault RestTemplate with Jackson Object mapping was taking ~3-4x time than postman call, while webclient took around same time.